# What is the runtime error in my Android Studio project?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, crash, runtime-error

In order to make the words minimal, I have attached the files to the link below, on Google Drive. I will only attach the runtime error in here.

Link:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11GiiPwRUKGJ3dLIRWsYO63JVGxwYymz1

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.wecarerestaurant.team, PID: 3155
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.wecarerestaurant.team/com.wecare.team.Dashboard}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at com.wecare.team.Dashboard.onCreate(Dashboard.java:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 2: TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0400c2 a=-1}
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawableForDensity(TypedArray.java:946)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:930)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:228)
        at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout.<init>(CollapsingToolbarLayout.java:151)
            ... 30 more
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3155 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8676', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: Part of the rules of Stack Overflow require the relevant files in the question itself. This has four close votes specifically because once the Google Drive link is deleted, the question will not make any sense to readers at that point.

Answer (score 0):

As your Error log has below line

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML
>   file line #17: Error inflating class
>   android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)

**Exception** - `InflateException`

**Error** in -  `XML` file  at line number 17.

**while** **inflating**  `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

Comment: @TeamWork-LebanonLtd. Check your XML fire .

Comment: what do you mean by checking my XML file ?

Comment: Means problem in your XML at line 17 and if you are using custom view from XML then there must be some error in that custom view